# refactoring - coworker interaction

Tags: refactoring

my only coworker used the following code execution to compile code to pdf

- compile to pdf (1st time): produce a first draft version and an .xlsx. but the only purpose is to create the .xlsx.
- compile the same file to pdf (2d time): look up in the previously created .xlsx to produce the pdf

To have the process in one pass, simplified and avoid a source of foreseeable bugs (2 pass compilation... hell), I mentioned that we could:

- reorganize the code
- use 'in-line' code functionality (code in the latex area)

his answer was something like

> well it works if you follow the step I describe so no need to change
>   it and it is written in the comments that you have to compile it twice.

I had to take the time to write the step on a paper. We let non-programmer run this code to produce reports. They don't read comments.

if I refactor the code he will really be upset, because it is not the way he started with plus as mentionned it works if you follow his instruction.

did you already faced it. how did you resolved it?

thanks

Comment: This question might be a better fit on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would like to then. but i can't migrate it...